Discord Bot is online But Does not reply on my discord channel
I am following a tutorial right now and i wrote exactly what the guy did and my $inspire command is not working.
The bot got all the permissions
import discord
import os
import requests
import json

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)


def get_quote():
  response = requests.get("https://zenquotes.io/api/ranom")
  json_data = json.loads(response.text)
  quote = json_data[0]['q'] + " -" + json_data[0]['a']
  return (quote)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('$inspire'):
    quote = get_quote()
    await message.channel.send(quote)


client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])

the code is in python and I am usign Replit to code this bot.
I was trying to get an inparation message from zenquotes.io and i was expecting a random quote everytime I type $inspire in my discord channel.

discord catch all errors and hide them - this way it can work even you made mistakes in code or in data. But you can change settings in logging to see all errors - and this may help. Check: Setting Up Logging

if you use requests then you can get directly response.json

when I open "https://zenquotes.io/api/ranom" in broser then I see JSON with Unrecognized API request. Visit zenquotes.io for documentation. Probably you forgot char d in word random - you have ranom

maybe first run only requests (without discord) to check if replit allows to access external servers. Some portals block access to other portals - to stop spamers or hackers.

I tested your code on local computer and it works for me when I write to bot private message but to work on server I need intents.message_content = True

see also Warning in documentation: Commands

I tested your code on local computer and it works for me when I write private message to bot but to work on channel I need intents.message_content = True
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client  = discord.Client(intents=intents)

See also Warning in documentation: Commands

BTW: you forgot char d in word random in url.

Full working code (with some small changes)
import os
import discord
import requests


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client  = discord.Client(intents=intents)


def get_quote():
    response = requests.get("https://zenquotes.io/api/random")
    data = response.json()
    item = data[0]
    quote = f"{item['q']} - {item['a']}"
    return quote


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    #print(client.user, message.author, message.content) 
    
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$inspire'):
        quote = get_quote()
        await message.channel.send(quote)


client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])

The same with commands
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)


def get_quote():
    response = requests.get("https://zenquotes.io/api/random")
    data = response.json()
    item = data[0]
    quote = f"{item['q']} - {item['a']}"
    return quote
    
    
@bot.command()
async def inspire(ctx):
    #print(dir(ctx))
    #print(ctx.me, ctx.author, ctx.message.content) 

    quote = get_quote()
    await ctx.send(quote)


bot.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])

